# $z = e^y \phi \left(y e^ \frac{x^2}{2y^2} \right)$ satisfies $(x^2 - y^2) \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + xy \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = xyz$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Show that the function $z = e^y \phi \left(y e^ \frac{x^2}{2y^2}\right)$ satisfies the equation $(x^2 - y^2) \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} + xy \frac{\partial z}{\partial y} = xyz$.

$\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = \dfrac{x}{y} e^ {y + \frac{x^2}{2y^2}} \phi ' \left(y e^ \frac{x^2}{2y^2}\right) $. In the same way $\frac{\partial z}{\partial y}$ is calculated. And then I did the multiplications but the calculation becomes very long.

Is there another way, for example with a change of variable, so that it is not so long?

Comment: Is $\phi$ an arbitrary function, and are the derivatives meant to be partial derivatives?

Comment: @Jonathan Davidson 1 Yes, $\phi$ is an arbitrary function and the derivatives meant to be partial derivatives.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$
\frac{dz}{dx} = e^y \phi'\frac{x}{y}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}
$$
$$
\frac{dz}{dy} = e^y\phi + e^y\phi'\left(e^\frac{x^2}{2y^2} - \frac{x^2}{y^2}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right)
$$
$$
(x^2-y^2)\frac{dz}{dx} + xy\frac{dz}{dy} = e^y \phi'\frac{x}{y}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}(x^2-y^2)+\left(e^y\phi + e^y\phi'\left(e^\frac{x^2}{2y^2} - \frac{x^2}{y^2}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right)\right)xy
$$
$$
e^y\phi xy+e^y\phi'\left(\frac{x}{y}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}(x^2-y^2)+\left(e^\frac{x^2}{2y^2} - \frac{x^2}{y^2}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right)xy\right)
$$
$$
e^y\phi xy+e^y\phi'\left(\frac{x^3}{y}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}-xye^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}+xye^\frac{x^2}{2y^2} - \frac{x^3}{y}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}\right) = xy e^y\phi = xyz
$$
$$
\therefore (x^2-y^2)\frac{dz}{dx} + xy\frac{dz}{dy} = xyz \quad z = e^y \phi
$$

Comment: $\frac{dz}{dx} = e^y \phi'\frac{x}{y}e^{\frac{x^2}{2y^2}}$, this is actually the partial derivative of z with respect to x. Or is it not?

Comment: yes miguel, it is correct

Answer (score 1):

**hint**
prove that

$$(x/y-y/x)\frac {dz}{dx}+\frac {dz}{dy}=z $$